# How do i get the error behind error 500 in .net core API

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a Vue front end and .netAPI backend.
The back-end does not pick up my file and gives me a 500 error.
How do i know what the 500 error means?

I tried with a collection of files passing just 'files'
and using IFormFileCollection. then i get a 400, does not even pick up the endpoint.

Vue:

```
        this.$axios.post(
        'https://localhost:44352/api/FileUpload/SendFiles',
        event.target.files[0],
        )  
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
```

API

```
        [HttpPost("[Action]")]
        [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public string SendFiles([FromBody]IFormFile files)
        {
            return "Yes!";
        }
```

The goal is getting the file inside the api.
Also after that, getting multiple files.

Comment: please post full error to see what actual happening in your case.

Comment: The title is 'how do i get the error behind error 500' :) 
Because i do not know how to get a better error.

Comment: I ended up turning the img into base64 and send it as a string.
I feel like Microsoft dropt the ball on this implementation

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that works for me

```
[HttpPost("[Action]")]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async string SendFiles()
    {
        var formData = await HttpContext.Request.ReadFormAsync();
        foreach (var file in formData.Files)
        { }
    }
```